# Apply multiple parametric functions over same data array

Tags: numpy

I have this code and it works well

```
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
parameters = np.array([[2, 0.5], [2]])
functions = np.array([lambda x, p: x + p[0]*p[1], lambda x, p: x * p[0]])

def f(data, parameters, functions):
    return np.array([f(data, p) for f, p in zip(functions, parameters)])

print(f(r))
```

This is the result

```
[[ 2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 2.  4.  6.  8. 10. 12.]]
```

But I think that there must be better way how to write the inside of the function `f()`. Function zip and list comprehension seems very ineffective to me. I would know what to do if there would not be functions but scalars, but functions and its parameters makes it hard.

This is only the example. Variables data, parameters and functions are numpy arrays I got from previous code. In here are set only to illustrate this example.

I would appreciate any advice. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to turn these into arrays int he first place?

Comment: They are basically inputs. I got them from previous code. I had to recreate them for this example. I changed the code to be more clear now.

Comment: Still, there no reason why `parameters` and `functions` should be numpy arrays. Using np doesn't add any performance here, on the contrary.

Comment: I don't think there's anyway to vectorise n functions with arbitrary number of inputs and outputs. You should find a pattern in the functions (for example they're all linear or something) then you concatenate the functions to get a vectorised function and apply that to your data.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher That is consequence of previous code which is not shown here. And np arrays are useful there. I will not convert them to lists only because they could be list right now and convert them back to arrays in following code because it will be necessary again.

Comment: numpy arrays of objects are not very good. Anyway, no, there is no better way of doing this.

Comment: @anishtain4 Those lambda functions will always have two parameters. In fact, they are written in a way that they don't care if x is an array or scalar value from cell of that array.

Comment: So you would always have two functions, one with two parameters and another with a single parameter?

Comment: @anishtain4 Unfortunately no. 1 - N functions with 0 - M parameters. There is no regularity in them.

Comment: The fast `numpy` array calculations are performed in compiled code (using C types like integer and double).  Your functions are written in Python.  Compiled code can't run those directly.  So you are stuck with Python level operations - like a list comprehension on zipped lists.

Comment: hpaulj is correct. You do not gain performance from using numpy array of functions. What you should (if you can) do, is bundle functions together: it is way faster to compute than a list of functions.